# How to remove address bar coming to webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I hava a webview showing some contents which is getting from server. Now on that same activity i use to override differnt urls based on condition. Means my webview is one and is loading differnt differnt page depending on the condition. 
Now in this webview bydefault I am getting address bar. Can anyone help me how to avoid addressbar coming to a webview.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6987190) answer is more fitting to the question. The address bar is coming from the external loading of a link in the built in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no address bar in a WebView. Question has already been stated here: [Disable address bar in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136362/disable-address-bar-in-android-webview)

What you probably wants is to remove the title. If I remember correctly the name/url is also stated in the title of the activity.
You should read: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

You could remove the title by writing this for your activity in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

2015 For Android Studio 1.0

Edit your manifest so theme looks like:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar"
```

Then open src/main/res/values/styles.xml and add the following:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And gone is the whatchamacallit bar